# Convert list to dictionary

Tags: c#

I have a list of these objects that I would like to convert to a dictionary:

```
public class Thing
{
    public Guid ParentKey { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public bool Unconfigured { get; set; }
    public void Replace(Thing thing);
}
```

I would like the key and value to be Thing objects where the ParentKey and Position are the same.  The key object must have Unconfigured set to true and the value would be a sibling object that has the same ParentKey and Position but a false Unconfigured state. I'm trying to create a pairs of objects that have the same ParentKey, Position but have different Unconfigured states.

Example:

```
var things = new List<Thing>();
things.Add(new Thing { ParentKey = new Guid("8a1211d2-f42b-4dd2-b6a3-7f4ab4a44a8d"), Position = 1, Unconfigured = true });
things.Add(new Thing { ParentKey = new Guid("8a1211d2-f42b-4dd2-b6a3-7f4ab4a44a8d"), Position = 1, Unconfigured = false });
things.Add(new Thing { ParentKey = new Guid("35f22dba-7789-49f4-8982-c9ea075175cc"), Position = 2, Unconfigured = false });
```

I expect a dictionary with one item.  The key for that item is the first thing object added and the value is the second thing object added.

The intended use of this is to call the replace method:

```
foreach (var entry in things)
{
     entry.Key.Replace(entry.Value);                                    
}
```

A dictionary may not be an appropriate object for this, I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: What would be the key of your Dictionary ?

Comment: list.ToDictionary(x=>x.key, x=>x.value);

Comment: I want the key to be the thing object itself.

Comment: @Robert if the object is the key, what is the value?

Comment: And the value should be what?

Comment: And the value would be a sibling object that meets the parameters I asked for.  I'm trying to create a pairs of objects that have the same ParentKey, Position but have different Unconfigured states.

Comment: btw  is it possible for you to show an example output with values?

Comment: Do you really need a dictionary or just a list of pairs of objects, one with Configured set and one with Configured unset? Please explain how you plan on using this dictionary so we can help you use the correct data type (as I think a dictionary may not be what you want to use)

Comment: @Amitd I have added an example

Comment: @ScottChamberlain A list of pairs would be sufficient.

Comment: @Robert so in your example, what would be the "value" for the 3rd item in the list. And what should happen if 3 objects had the same `ParentKey` and `Position`? Also please explain on how you are using this information as a Dictionary is most likely not the correct thing to use but we can't tell you what the correct thing would be without knowing what you are trying to do with it. You have fallen in to the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Don't ask about your solution (the dictionary) ask about the problem that caused you to try this solution.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The 3rd item in the list would not be in the dictionary.  If three objects had the same ParentKey and Position, I would expect duplicate entries in the dictionary

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I updated my question with how I'm using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to resort to a foreach loop, you can try the code below:

```
List<Thing> things = new List<Thing>();
Dictionary<Thing, Thing> dictionary = new Dictionary<Thing,Thing>();

var keys = from thing in things
           where thing.Unconfigured
           select thing;

var values = from thing in things
             where !thing.Unconfigured
             select thing;

foreach (Thing key in keys)
{
    var value = (from thing in values
                 where thing.ParentKey == key.ParentKey &&
                       thing.Position == key.Position
                 select thing).FirstOrDefault();
    dictionary.Add(key, value);
}
```

Of course the code assumes that you only have pairs in the List if there may be more than a pair of objects related in the way you described this would need revision

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
var dic = things.ToDictionary(
   t => new Thing
   {
       ParentKey = t.ParentKey,
       Position = t.Position,
       Unconfigured = true
   }, 
   t => new Thing
   {
       ParentKey = t.ParentKey,
       Position = t.Position,
       Unconfigured = false
   }
);
```

Comment: This does not take into consideration the ParentKey

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: what's the point of instantiating `new Thing`? you can just do `things.ToDictionary(t=>t)`

Comment: To set Unconfigured = true for the key.

Comment: I don't want to set it to true, please take a look at the edited question.

Comment: Note that you may find it hard to get things out of the dictionary if `Equals` and `GetHashCode` is not implemented on `Thing`. If you don't have those implmented the only way to get things out would be either `foreach` over the whole dictionary or pass in the exact same instance of the key that was generated new in the `ToDictionary` process.